# Meteor 1.6.0.1 & Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I ran "meteor add twbs:bootstrap" and am running Meteor 1.6.0.1, however the style is not coming in. The font did change in the body, so this must mean bootstrap is properly brought into my project. Are you supposed to import the CSS anywhere? Any insights?

[image]

On the console, the below code is what is being output from localhost:3000. From this we can see that a stylesheet is in fact coming in with the class "*meteor-css*". When I try to bring in the CDN link for bootstrap style (commented out below) the style still does not display correctly. Could it be there is a stylesheet somewhere that is overriding bootstrap?

```
<html><head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=1ae8af9d87a4273fc0f18106718d825f62705bb4">
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Microposts</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" ,="" initial-scale="1," minimal-ui,="" maximum-scale="1," minimum-scale="1">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

</head>
<body>



  <script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.6.0.1%22%2C%22meteorEnv%22%3A%7B%22NODE_ENV%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22TEST_METADATA%22%3A%22%7B%7D%22%7D%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appId%22%3A%22yzak68srh69.bnzp2k91exj%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%22e033eae1400e6bfb9ad77a813be6f768bdfdb378%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%222123f271cca18ad6e1613e9c98314fffe56740b5%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%22none%22%7D"))</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?hash=cbcc712d51de4298c275e8dcf25c66c29914f19a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor-base.js?hash=a4d07a6b394e56bbe6ccc773c95e7cdb3434960d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mobile-experience.js?hash=8ded3e69a3e367f321ab9a2b52e3ecdd2661a365"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-compiler.js?hash=a9546d4e245cfe40b406e08d40bf106241f01683"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript.js?hash=370a8752194bcf73be7fffa3635715d0fbf7853d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/base64.js?hash=0053489bb30bb5c0e3545df151f83e41150344b0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=5e485d3e2a49d2506f7ca0df72fcd6a3216a83a5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules.js?hash=03b6ee70345231327c4093f5e3f0de2f62eaf54a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime.js?hash=ed0d1c9624ff822ac7a673101e02acc5a1471a22"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7aa1536cb75430d62c9dad8eaffe2b3716"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/promise.js?hash=4d9496fe1e551fede71efe67cf7f48d19015fd90"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-runtime.js?hash=92770f08ed6cf73de1a4c0e25610b170df975dff"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=236033036aa3b0629009d2af14113e2413052567"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?hash=3af8c8d41c63ca01c1c9698a677bc5ae971ff3b2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/geojson-utils.js?hash=e9d235fa7a29b6bcb50d7ad0b05751fa169fcc8b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?hash=189ef930765405ef87a31a621407fc34447b8756"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?hash=bacdd1852075630a01f7de783e5e8e8aa8541cdc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?hash=2b34314db9dbc6027d9d414887b75281c4515a19"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/callback-hook.js?hash=e15ed8aa52e7c647efd9f4854e8a0fe4e40808fc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=df770fd9a6a02fd730939b97d266ea2b12938e95"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-server.js?hash=1beefbc7bd033ea687e7ab8fbd5694df072662af"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/allow-deny.js?hash=74d8af62e9bac0bd3c45b254bad987e996a88f6e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-dev-server.js?hash=ffb3e3929e33d217163e7dce36aff2c85ec727d3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/insecure.js?hash=a0e5f17c280f4c7b05178d36a7ceb07cb7b086c6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze-html-templates.js?hash=6e8335ce66460e45f00da73c7497654c5e26e236"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-var.js?hash=ec712fa3ae588c4a1e7017f0bb4507c725391225"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-css.js?hash=cfe82682f4394d3ffc6335555c1f9f3f73294507"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-js.js?hash=041bab58c8a89172eaab795deb5d96e38b64ec37"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/shell-server.js?hash=6ff1313e4bf7618e577eb2604a580b2ea9b7631f"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autopublish.js?hash=073bd4c42d2fb6182c944501b4f30e8d17bcceb3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/deps.js?hash=7313f5a2685c6c2c673c78c15c8ce86ff59ab0c9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?hash=e5fc9cebb2e37c48ddfaf76e0ab0b77cb6ce6e52"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=8fe58036c6ba00c458f54c360a21fd0e41fb7ee0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/htmljs.js?hash=1ac878018eee6c53ed1375dc7ee75fc6865666ae"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ui.js?hash=039c55a98376abd03d9d8cd4100895861b897643"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating-compiler.js?hash=a71883cdec50e95ca135291415990753ed6d57fc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating-runtime.js?hash=c18de19afda6e9f0db7faf3d4382a4c953cabe18"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating.js?hash=c2cf38de06efb47f67affb2dff9320e5eef33893"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_core.js?hash=eb27a7eaa0318536b619a36fbd2c9d45cd833bc9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?hash=7644dc7260de827ef1e361a75159fcc8af9fc074"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_layout.js?hash=b2030df3beb941a1eb0eeaf4d68c7f4c145ec14a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_url.js?hash=5677fc5d3197491431965b2e0746b613c84076e0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=e5ffae14128fa7f2aa1e3c04bb343146e1dfec09"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_location.js?hash=1a6ee647a94fae1d34d1b5074ec4dfebfe6f1bd3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-dict.js?hash=36dba3ca2e22f021d4d49ea7a60e99b03349a689"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_controller.js?hash=eb63ea93809dcd3a8f40ad258e0997969a4d3ebc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron_router.js?hash=f36af52c3c2c3d66f1e99d1562e7d6bf92b00c1c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/twbs_bootstrap.js?hash=2ee228e6c80c1d9a4b1e67e10006f8a5a425ddda"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?hash=266b2d6adf1a164ef9db120ea9c68d5658351399"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/dynamic-import.js?hash=d20b3dfd7dd31096c4c95f8751141e932cabc923"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/hot-code-push.js?hash=2e864a0bdd0d5f686115099f8c48eb6c866b5b14"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/launch-screen.js?hash=2f56943306c7e900ed9f4d894b87f534ebffeaeb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/global-imports.js?hash=22a68bcdd0082d49a005ee38bbdaa61bcc8688fd"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js?hash=fb8c074a097f61e7e3d6ea06707ab9449b3a78da"></script>



  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
  This is posts</body></html>
```

Comment: What does your page source look like?

Comment: Within my template tags, I have copied the <nav> from this bootstrap template: view-source:http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/

Comment: What you claim to have used isn't the same as what your page is rendering.  Show us the code that is displaying on `localhost:3000` and *then* we can troubleshoot what is going on.

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/angelicavalenta/micropost I also tried using CDN style link tag. This made the style more closely resemble bootstrap, but not completely. Could it be that by running "meteor create app" it included some style that is overiding bootstrap style?

Comment: We really need to see the final output, not your GitHub repository.  Instead of a screenshot of what is rendered, show us the code that is output.

Comment: Hi Robert - I appreciate your help. I have updated to include the code.

Comment: I see that a separate `<link>` for Bootstrap's CSS is commented out.  Can you verify if your `merged-stylesheets.css` is merging Bootstrap in correctly?  Also, can you verify that the CSS and JS being included is Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Correct, I commented the CDN <link> out because the package should provide me with the styling. When the CDN <link> isn't commented out, the styling is still not accurate. After running "meteor add twbs:bootstrap" and looking at the versions file, it displays "twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6". I have not added any of my own CSS, so I am not sure where "merged-stylesheets.css" comes from or how it is related to the bootstrap package.

Comment: So one potential problem: If Meteor is inserting Bootstrap 3 you can't use the Bootstrap 4 Starter Template.  The `Nav` component uses different structure in 4 than it did 3.

Comment: Don't use the meteor package, it is not updated. Instead include bootstrap via `meteor npm install --save bootstrap` which gives you the latest stable version. You can also then use the latest version 4.0.0, if explicitly installed

Comment: That SOLVED it!! So it appears the problem was that by using the meteor package "twbs:bootstrap" Bootstrap 3 was installed and not compatible with the starter template I was using. By using meteor npm install --save bootstrap this installed Bootstrap 4 which works for the starter template code. 
As a follow up, when I use meteor npm bootstrap, the files load in Node Modules. Is best practice not to use the Bootstrap CDN link/scrips? Should I use an "import" line somewhere in my code to pull in the JS/CSS from the Node Modules folder somehow.

Comment: For me the problem with npm is you should manually import things and manually enable BS js plugins. I ended up using cdn in layout template (see at the [end of the file](https://github.com/rmuratov/livepolls/blob/master/imports/ui/layouts/layout/layout.html#L37-L40))